# I need to know the Big O time of my binary heap code and if there are improvements

Tags: java

I need to know what the Big O time of my binary heap code is, and how can I improve it?

Here's the code:

```
public static void CreateMaxHeap(int[] a)
{
    for (int heapsize = 0; heapsize < a.Length; heapsize++)
    {
        int n, p;
        n = heapsize;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            p = (n - 1) / 2;
            if(a[n]>a[p])
                Swap(a,n,p);
            n = p;
        }
    }
} // end of create heap
```

Comment: Have what have you tried? Do you have any ideas? We're not just going to *do* your homework for you.

Comment: ha ha..I mean Big O.........
Yaa i tried  I think its O(nlogn), as I am using top down approach to create a binary heap from an array

Comment: swaps the array elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's O(nlgn)

you iterate through the entire array that takes O(n). but every iteration you go back through the array by dividing by 2 repeatedly. so every iteration you're adding the lgn to it which is **log base 2 of n**.

as for making it better, the first thing i see is that when **heapsize** is zero, nothing happens. that's kindof wasteful of resources... so maybe start at 1. that's all.

Comment: Cool...I got it....how can I make it better. This talks about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort....here there is a bottom up approach which it says that it runs in O(n) time....but I am not able to understand how?

Comment: you don't understand how it's O(n) or you don't understand how to implement it?

Comment: @Learner - Where does it say that it's O(n)?  The article mentions smoothsort, which is still O(nlgn), but gets close to O(n) if the input is somewhat sorted already.

Comment: thisThe heapify function can be thought of as building a heap from the bottom up, successively shifting downward to establish the heap property. An alternative version (shown below) that builds the heap top-down and shifts upward is conceptually simpler to grasp. This "siftUp" version can be visualized as starting with an empty heap and successively inserting elements. However, it is asymptotically slower: the "siftDown" version is O(n), and the "siftUp" version is O(n log n) in the worst case. The heapsort algorithm is O(n log n) overall using either version of heapify. is what article says

Comment: victor: I understand how it is implemented, what I don't understand it how is it O(n), the siftDown function....

Comment: The O(n) relays on the fact that the you are doing O(n) actions, but not all of them are ln(n) some are shorter actions, if you do the math, it can be proven to be O(n). There's a prove on 

http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262032937

Comment: The whole O(n) thing comes from initially creating a heap before sorting, not the sorting itself. Here's the proof that the heapify method is O(n) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap